# How to create integer function with variable that doesn't reset each increment

Tags: function, variables

I am trying to create a mini football game that gives each player a certain amount of yards every time I press ENTER. I think the problem I am having is that I can't think of a way to to make a variable to add the yards together from each turn. When the first function does initialize I get a stack overflow recurse error. I also can't get the first function to initialize. I don't know if that is connected.

Here is what I have so far

```
package Football;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class FootballGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int l = 0;
    int m = 0;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("       THIS IS VIRTUAL FOOTBALL!");
System.out.println("In order to to take your turn and gain yards all you have to do is press ENTER");
System.out.println("First type your names");

System.out.println("player 1?");
String player1 = in.nextLine();


System.out.println("player 2?");
String player2 = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("OK! Lets play.");
in.next();

l = firstPlayer(player1, player2, l);
    }

public static int firstPlayer(String player1, String player2, int l)
    {
    for(int i = 0; i >= 100; i++ )
        {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rv = 0;
        int y = r.nextInt(21);
        l = (y + l);
        System.out.println(player1 + " gained " + y + " yards for a total of " + l + " yards");
        if(rv < 100)
        {
        secondPlayer(player1, player2, l);
        }
    if (l >= 100)
        {
        System.out.println("TOUCHDOWN!");
        System.out.println("praise the lord almighty Jesus Jehova, God up above.");
        break;
        }

}
    return l;
    }



public static int secondPlayer(String player1, String player2, int m)
    {
    for(int i = 0; i >= 100; i++)
        {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rv = 0;
        int y = r.nextInt(21);
        m = (y + m);
        System.out.println(player2 + " gained " + y + " yards for a total of" + m + " yards");
        if(m < 100)
        {
        firstPlayer(player1, player2, m);
        }
    if (m >= 100)
        {
            System.out.println("TOUCHDOWN!");
            System.out.println(player2 + " cheated and won the game");
            break;
        }
    }
    return m;

    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i stopped reading the code as soon as i noticed this:  `for(int i = 0; i >= 100; i++ )`. this loop is never going to run

Comment: i needed a 'break' and that is the only way i know how. by adding the for-loop

Comment: @mangusta Thank You for your comment. It looks like it was what I needed to get it to work. I just took away the for loop and the breaks